# What is the current fastest algorithm for finding the maximum common subgraph?

Tags: graphs, graph-isomorphism

First of all, it's my first time in #ComputerScience at StackExchange so, my apologies if I'm making some newbie mistake when asking this question.

So, I'm currently researching algorithms for finding the maximum common subgraph isomorphism and after reading a lot of papers I'm still confused about what is the state-of-the-art algorithm for finding the maximum common subgraph between 2 graphs. Also, all the algorithms I've read about work with 2 graphs (directed or undirected) but none directly work with more than 2 graphs.

In summary, my questions are:

1. Which is considered the fastest/state-of-the-art algorithm for finding the MCSI? Is it the VF2 algorithm?
2. Also, does this algorithm work with more than 2 graphs at the same time?
3. Any alternate algorithm that works with N graphs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the site! :-)